# How to merge objects of array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to merge objects of an array in the aggregation pipeline. Here is MongoDB Document.

```
{
    "category" : [
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("60ed3d041436f1310401b1b2"),
            "name" : "cat 1",
            "services" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("607ab64bc520c2587045694b"),
                    "name" : "service 1",
        
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    "category" : [
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("60ed3cff1436f1310401b1b1"),
            "name" : "cat 2",
            "services" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffd5d4bc4967a1b10bf5022"),
                    "name" : "service 2",
                
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("60ed3cff1436f1310401b1b1"),
            "name" : "cat 2",
            "services" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("6077e777ad481470d42c4e41"),
                    "name" : "service 3",
                    
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected Output**
I need to merge the `category` array into one and merge the `service` array  based on the category

```
     [
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("60ed3d041436f1310401b1b2"),
            "name" : "cat 1",
            "services" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("607ab64bc520c2587045694b"),
                    "name" : "service 1",
        
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("60ed3cff1436f1310401b1b1"),
            "name" : "cat 2",
            "services" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffd5d4bc4967a1b10bf5022"),
                    "name" : "service 2",
                
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("6077e777ad481470d42c4e41"),
                    "name" : "service 3",
                    
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

How to achieve this ?.

Comment: Not possible! You cannot have just an array inside an object.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$category" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: "$category.name"
      },
      services: { $push: { $first: "$category.services" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: "$_id.name",
      services: 1
    }
  }
])
```

See [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XcmWrU0AFRo)

Comment: I got an error .MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$first'

Comment: Which mongo version do you use? Try `{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$category.services", 0 ] }` instead.

Comment: mongoDB version "4.2.2"

Comment: Could you please explain the complete code by using 
`$arrayElemAt`

Comment: Should be obvious: `{ $first: "$category.services" }` -> `{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$category.services", 0 ] }`

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer